# How do I implement a sliding interface on my app to slide between screens left and right

Tags: android, android-layout

Such as used in the play store, how you can swipe left and right to switch been Top paid/top free/top grossing/top new, etc. What is this style of swiping actually called and how can I implement it into my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using `ViewPager`.

Check out the official guide [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). To got the titles on top, use [PagerTabStrip](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can override `overridePendingTransition()` when you switch to an intent, for more info: [Checkout the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition%28int,%20int%29)

I believe the transition you are looking for is something like:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.transition_to_right, R.anim.transition_to_left);
```